# Is there an efficient way to organize a multi-dimension array by two or more items?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of arrays like this:

```
Array[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]...]
```

Where the two-element arrays are composed by an integer ID on position 0 and a timestamp on position 1. All elements were parsed from json, therefore they are strings. I get these values from a mySQL database.

I have multiple occurences of the same ID and the array is sorted by timestamp, like so:

```
Array[0] = {"50", "datetime"}
Array[1] = {"49", "datetime"}
Array[2] = {"45", "datetime"}
Array[3] = {"50", "datetime"}
Array[4] = {"45", "datetime"}
```

I would like to organize the array in blocks of same IDs and ordered by timestamp, like so:

```
Array[0] = {"50", "datetime0"}
Array[1] = {"50", "datetime1"}
Array[2] = {"49", "datetime0"}
Array[3] = {"49", "datetime1"}
Array[4] = {"45", "datetime0"}
```

Would it be more efficient to do it on the client side via javascript or is there a way I can do it on mySQL?

*fellows help get my sleep back*

Comment: Using SQL should be the easiest way to do this. For example, try ORDER BY myId ASC, myDatetime ASC after your WHERE statement. This, however, should be pretty easy to find out using google ;)

Comment: Yes, you can easily do this with [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Jesus Christ! How couldnt I think of this. Changed the SQL query to order by ID and sorted the array with javascript. Thanks a lot @tagelicht.

Comment: It can be done in SQL and in JS but i think it would be more efficient to do it in the SQL query itself, since the server is sorting the produced items anyways in some default so might as well skip that and give it the desired order straight up. Also i think generally SQL does these things faster but that might be wrong.

Comment: @MarcoTulioSouza with a bit more sql you could reach the sorted output completely through it. Again i think it would be beneficial for performance but not sure.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Is there any way to close the topic without removing the question?

Comment: On Stack Overflow questions needs answers, problems require solutions. If there is an answer that solves your problem then mark it as accepted. Otherwise add your own answer, describing how you solved the problem, and mark it as accepted answer. Alternatively you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice from @tagelicht I solved the problem on mySQL side using:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Since in my database all items were already ordered by timestamp no more coding was required.

*despair and lack of sleep makes you dumb*

Answer (score 0):

and there is one more thing to make it scalable while using sql as mentioned above,
add indexing for these two fields so query would be much much faster